# Set title bar programmatically

Tags: meta-tags

I have to set, programmatically, the title value of pages, only for browser title bar (this value is stored in a metatags_quick field)
If I use "drupal_set_title" I change also the title displayed in page, I've only to change the window title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `hook_preprocess_html()` to override this value:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['head_title'] = 'Some other title';
}
```

The title for the content won't be affected by that, just the `<title>` tag.

Comment: Ok, only one thing: on D7 the hook should like this:
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['head_title'] = 'Some other title';
}

Comment: Sorry about that I left the `$vars` out of the function signature...it's fixed now